# JSON Where Clauses : whereJsonContains on laravel

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, laravel, get

I have problem about queries on laravel.
here is code on laravel :

```
$tabel_data= \App\Models\Data::where('data_keys','element')
->whereJsonContains('data_values->trx_type','withdraw')
->get();
```

here is data on mysql:

```
INSERT INTO `Data`(`id`, `data_keys`, `data_values`) 
VALUES ('300','element','{"id":"300","trx_type":"withdraw","name":"John","date":"2021-09-12","amount":"10","gateway":"USD"}')
```

the query should be

```
select * from `Data` where `data_keys` = 'element'and JSON_CONTAINS(data_values, '"withdraw"', '$.trx_type');
```

but when running the code it changes to

```
select * from `Data` where `data_keys` = 'element' and JSON_CONTAINS(`data_values`, '\"withdraw\"', '$."trx_type"')
```

so it was automatically added the character `\"..\"` at `'\"withdraw\"'` and `"..."`at `'$."trx_type"'`.

it makes my query not get the data. so how can i fix it. thanks for your help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i have solved my problem

edit code on laravel is:

```
$tabel_data= \App\Models\Data::where('data_keys','element') ->whereJsonContains('data_values',['trx_type'=>'withdraw') ->get();
```

this worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).